# What if I upgrade XUbuntu? Won't it turn into Ubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, release-upgrade

My XUbuntu  11.10 offers me to upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04. But I don't want Ubuntu, I want XUbuntu!

Answer (score 3):

Yes! Updater upgrades same package set you have and so it sticks to Xubuntu.